# jQuery ajax crossdomain request on mobile phone

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, mobile

I am writing kind of an API to get a login panel from my own server. The plan is, that every domain, which I allow in my PHP header

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: externaldomain.com")
```

can access the login panel.

It is working really fine but I do have a problem when I try to get the login panel with my smartphone.

I have this bit of javascript code:

### myAPI.js

```
function __getLoginPanel(developerapikey)
{
    var hostname = location.hostname;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data:{host:hostname, devkey:developerapikey},
        url: "http://www.example.com/loginPanel.php",
        success: function(htmlresponse) {
            $(".placeHolderLoginPanel").html(htmlresponse); 
        }   
    });
}
```

and my loginPanel.php looks like this (nothing special)

### loginPanel.php

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="devkey" value="<?php echo $_POST['devkey']; ?>">  
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <input type="password" id="passwort" name="passwort">
    <input type="button" name="loginSubmit" value="Login">
</form>
```

When I call the API from another server like this:

### my external php file which calls the API

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/myAPI.js"></script>
var developerapikey = "abc"; 
__getLoginPanel(developerapikey);
```

it only works in the browser. Very fast and nothing's wrong.

But when I call the website with my smart phone, nothing happens.

I've read something about

```
crossDomain: true
```

in the ajax call, but nothing changes.

Please help me out :-)

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, everything is alright. It was an error in the Origin Header in my php file.